# Quartz Scheduler pausing running job internally upon shutdown?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am noticing that sometimes quartz scheduler is automatically pausing some of the jobs. Is this a bug or any configuration issue?

All scheduled jobs are using CronTrigger.

I am suspecting that whenever server is stopped, it maybe automatically pausing running job? I have following code for ServletContextListener for shutdown of application.

```
public void shutdownScheduler(Scheduler scheduler) {
    try {
        if (null != scheduler) {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

Some of the quartz properties are listed below...

```
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it does go to standBy mode by default.** If you check the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.3/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.java#QuartzScheduler.shutdown%28boolean%29) you will see that one of the first thing the code does after calling shutdown is invoking the `standby()` function.

If you want to avoid this behaviur, you have the option to call shutdown with a parameter:

```
shutdown(true)
```

which will force the `Scheduler` to wait for running jobs to complete first.
Confirmation is in the [doc](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#shutdown%28%29), but not too much about the details unfortunately.

Comment: But it doesn't raise 'jobPaused', which is main issue for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "raise jobPaused"?

Comment: architecture of current product is around 'SchedulerListener' and there are some other local product logic needs to be executed if SchedulerListener.jobPaused is raised by Quartz Scheduler. It looks like that Quartz is raising this intermediately.

Comment: Oh, I see. notifySchedulerListenersPausedJobs() is not called indeed, but  notifySchedulerListenersInStandbyMode() is being called, so probably you need to start listening on that too.